# What are the consequences of accessing the same database from different programs at the same time?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have a mysql database that is accessed using JDBC. If I access the database from two different programs at the same time then what effect will be there on the database?

Please tell in view of when both programs are reading the database, one is reading and the other is writing data and when both are writing data.

I think that when both programs write data then that would definitely lead to loss of data. But what happens in the other scenarios?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-multi-versioning.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL works on an ACID basis: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

Which means, both clients will be reading the database as if they were the only clients.

For this to happen each client must start a transaction, which is a single logical unit of work. Within this transaction either all the operations done to the database must be committed or rolled back.

Different RDBMSs have different defaults for their transaction support. For MySQL, the isolation level is [REPEATABLE READ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read), which means that SELECT statements within the same transaction are consistent with respect to each other.

How you can verify this:

Have program1 going start a transaction and through every row and increasing a value, while the other program starts a transaction and goes through the database calculating the sum of the same value for all rows. When they are done, they close their transactions and print out the results. You will notice that both of them read the database as if they were isolated from each other.

There are whole books written about JDBC. Here are some links that can get you started:

JDBC Tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/

MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html

Comment: "Which means, both clients will be reading the database as if they were the only clients." --- it highly depends on the chosen transaction isolation level. I'd say that in most cases what you said is not true.

Comment: Your example will always work fine : none of the 2 programs will break. But the result of the program calculating the sum is **highly** dependant on isolation level. In TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE, it will be be value before the other transaction begins. In TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED, it will use updated values as soon as the other transation will be commited, and in TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED it will be as if the other transaction was committing after each update. Not sure the transactions are really independant !..

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully, MySQL like PostgreSQL, MariaDB or other major databases accept to be used by many programs, each being allowed to have many connections. And the database will not break even if multiple programs try to update the same row at the same time. But ... the how to do that **is the problem of the client programs** via transactions.

Welcome to the world of [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) transactions ! Within a transaction, the database guarantees that the program keeps a level of consistency. There is no problems for Atomicity, Consistency and Durability, but Isolation is a little more tedious. JDBC defines 4 level of isolation, plus no transaction at all (following extracted from [The Java Tutorials : Using Transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html)) :

The interface Connection includes five values that represent the transaction isolation levels you can use in JDBC:

```
Isolation Level                 Transactions    Dirty Reads     Non-Repeatable   Reads/Phantom Reads
TRANSACTION_NONE                Not supported   Not applicable  Not applicable   Not applicable
TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED      Supported       Prevented       Allowed          Allowed
TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED    Supported       Allowed         Allowed          Allowed
TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ     Supported       Prevented       Prevented        Allowed
TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE        Supported       Prevented       Prevented        Prevented
```

Accessing an updated value that has not been committed is considered a dirty read because it is possible for that value to be rolled back to its previous value.

A non-repeatable read occurs when transaction A retrieves a row, transaction B subsequently updates the row, and transaction A later retrieves the same row again. Transaction A retrieves the same row twice but sees different data.

A phantom read occurs when transaction A retrieves a set of rows satisfying a given condition, transaction B subsequently inserts or updates a row such that the row now meets the condition in transaction A, and transaction A later repeats the conditional retrieval. Transaction A now sees an additional row. This row is referred to as a phantom.

Comment: "Within a transaction, the database *guarantees* that the program keeps a level of consistency" --- depending on a chosen transaction isolation level there might be data anomalies.

Comment: it's actually wonderfully detailed! I just commented about a particular phrase about "guaranteed" thing.